# Send a dynamic parameter to a jQuery function from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In code behind I have the following code that gets the [IDphoto] from an SQL database. Now I want to send the IDphoto as a parameter to a jQuery function onClick. How can I do that?

Code behind

```
sb.AppendFormat("<a onclick='popup()' href='#" + IDphoto + "'>");
```

jQuery

```
function popup() {        
$(document).ready(function () { 
// Here I want to get the value of IDphoto ...         
});
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated the codes based on TrueBlueAussie reply:

```
photos_sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"#\" class=\"photo\"  data-photo=\"" + IDphoto + "\">");


$(document).ready(function () { 
// Here I want to get the value of IDphoto ...         
$('a.photo').click(function(e){
      // Stop the link click from moving to the page top
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr("data-photo");
      alert(id);
});
});
```

Nothing is happening. The click doesn't fire the jQuery function!

Comment: Additional note. Use double-quotes around HTML attributes as a general rule (not single quotes). While most browsers accept either it just smells wrong :)

Comment: Additional-additional note: A DOM ready handler *inside a click handler* is a complete waste of time. The DOM will certainly be ready before that link is clicked :)

Comment: Please show a browser "save-as" of the output HTML so I can mockup my example in a JSFiddle. :)

Comment: Working example of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wqkxwz2j/

Answer (score 2):

A few words of advice:

- Do not use inline `onclick` attribute handlers with jQuery. That adds unneeded complexity and separation of the event code from the event registration code.
- Use double-quote on HTML attribute values. Most browser accept either, but double-quoting is safer for compatibility.
- Also use `data-` attributes to provide meta-data (rather than bury it in the href). Make the href a plain bookmark link (#).
- Use a common class on any photo links to allow simpler jQuery matching (and styling):
- `$(function(){...});` is a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
  e.g

  sb.AppendFormat("");

and add a jQuery click handler that looks for clicks on any `.photo` links:

```
$(function () { 
// Here I want to get the value of IDphoto ...         
    $('a.photo').click(function(e){
          // Stop the link click from moving to the page top
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).attr("data-photo");
          alert(id);
    });
});
```

Here is a mockup of the above using some sample links:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wqkxwz2j/

Comment: I followed your instructions but nothing is happening. The function is not fired and no error! Please see update above!

Comment: I cannot of course confirm you have followed my instructions without seeing your complete code again. Barring any typos the above code *will* work for non-dynamic elements. If you are adding photos dynamically (via Ajax etc) you will need a change to this code a little (let me know).

Answer (score 0):

why not just send the IDphoto to same popup function from your Code-Behind:

```
sb.AppendFormat("<a onclick='popup("+IDphoto+")' href='#" + IDphoto + "'>");
```

jQuery

```
function popup(myVarID) {        
$(document).ready(function () { 
// Here I want to get the value of IDphoto ...         
});
}
```

Comment: Not that I recommend inline handlers with jQuery at all, but a *DOM ready* handler in the middle of the click handler is kind of obsolete wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: It is indeed. I am just as surprised as you are, why in the world of Coders did I do that. I probably should remove the DOM ready handler from my answer or the answer itself. Latter sounds better, wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: It was in the original, so not surprised it stayed. *Trust nothing* should be our catch phrase on SO (remove it from your answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understand what you want. But here is example:

Code behind:

```
sb.AppendFormat("<a onclick='popup("+IDphoto +")' href='#'>");
```

Javascript

```
function popup(IDphoto) {       
    console.log(IDphoto);
}
```